# angularjs directive: not replace nor transclude

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to append a directive's template AFTER an input field.  The original input field *needs* to remain - I can't just create a duplicate of it.  My thought for this was to, in the controller, use jQuery to add a DIV after the input field, and add an attribute for the directive to the div.  However, in practice, that doesn't work - the div is created and added, but the directive doesn't activate.

The problem, I know, is that the jQuery-added div is not yet recognized by the angularjs controller - it appears AFTER angularjs runs over the controlled html.

I know that part of the problem is that you're not supposed to use jQuery in the controller, but I honestly can't think of another way to do it.  Is there some way to cause the angularjs controller to look at this new div?

The original HTML looks like the following.

```
<input name="generatedString_1234567890">
```

I run jquery over the page to add a controller to the body.  The relevant code looks similar to this:

```
jQuery('body').attr('ng-controller','MainCtrl');
angular.module('app',['DataTools']);
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Inside the angularjs, I run a resource to get a json string containing the relevant changes to the DOM, in terms of attributes that need to get added to the inputs and certain understood flags that require specific coding.  The relevant task I'm trying to accomplish looks like this, where `$(this)` is the input field for the DOM.

```
jQuery(document).find('input.FormField,select.FormField').each(function(){

    // Inside a case statement based on certain flags

    var d = $('<div/>');
    d.attr("ng-model", 'adors.'+label);
    // Relevant code that adds attributes to the div - including the required directives
    $(this).hide().after(d);

}
```

I am trying to create code that looks more like this (VERY GENERIC):

```
<input name="generatedString_1234567890" ng-hide="true" ng-model="input.uniqueKey">
<div special-input="time" ng-model="input.uniqueKey">
    <select ng-repeat="hour in hours">
    <select ng-repeat="minute in minutes">
</div>
```

Comment: why can't the input be replaced? depends in a view is usually a bad sign...

Comment: @dandavis because the form generated is a dynamically generated automatic form that the angularjs is being pasted onto after the fact, and the directive is an attempt to create a more client-responsive interface that the user needs.  I bind the same $scope variable to both the original (then hidden) input field and the new responsive input fields so that a change in my input field will fill a value into the auto-generated form's input field, and the CMS will never know the difference.

Comment: without seeing the code, i would suggest that you probably have to hide more of the orig interface and update the hidden parts from angular. you could also look into spoofing the submit instead of the UI. Personally, i've never had very good luck with spoofing inputs; something always breaks somewhere down the line...

Comment: @dandavis spoofing the submit has been ... problematic.  Especially in IE.  We tried that for a while.  We can do this piecemeal well enough if we hide more of the original interface and update the hidden parts from angular, too - we've been doing that for a while.  But by now we have so many custom forms that our directories are bloated with them, and it's making it hard to update the original software.  We're trying to develop a more flexible method where the customized UX changes can be run from a database - and for that, we need to do it input by input.  TLDR: Did that.  Need something new

Comment: @dandavis I added some code snippets as per your request.